# Does the sorting hat distribute students equally?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, sorting-hat

A series of questions, so I'll split them up if needed.

I'm working my way through the books again and was wondering if the sorting hats sorts the students into houses equally, or if there are some houses which have a larger number of students than others (two questions I guess).

If they are sorted equally, can we therefore say hat Hogwarts has around 800 pupils, as in *The Prisoner of Azkaban* in the Gryffindor Vs. Slytherin Quidditch match, it's said that the '200 Slytherin's boo'd Gryffindoor as they walked onto the pitch' (roughly, can't remember the exact text)?

Comment: [Smells dupey](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7907/31051)

Comment: yeah most of your questions are answered in jasons link

Comment: Ah, wrong search criteria.  Never thought to use "quota" as a keyword missed it when looking through.  Agreed it's a duplicate then.  Should I delete it or will a moderator do what's needed?

Comment: Do not delete it. Duplicates are good for searching. We like to keep them around.