# In which Hogwarts House would each of the Peverell brothers be in?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, sorting-hat

Had the Peverell brothers been at Hogwarts, which house would each of them have been Sorted into?

I assume their respective choices of hallows is reflective of their traits and desires.

Just so everyone knows which brother had which hallow:

- Antioch: Elder Wand
- Cadmus: Resurrection Stone
- Ignotus: Cloak of Invisibility

Comment: I am waiting for Slytherincess to answer this question!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Actually, the books answer this question. After all, the Harry Potter series is about three people :

1. **Harry Potter** : The Boy who lives, defies death time and again and escapes from the tightest of spots. Relatively unattracted by power. In a way, he represents Ignotus. That he is a descendant from Ignotus, owns (and chooses to keep) the Invisibility cloak is just a plot device to confirm this.
2. **Tom Riddle a.k.a Voldemort** : Power hungry. Supremely confident about his abilities. Spends most of his time plotting ways to cheat and humiliate death, and even succeeds once. He portrays the characteristics of Antioch. Like Antioch, he finally ends up with the Elder wand, which in turn brings about his downfall.
3. **Albus Dumbledore** : Wise, although misguided and flawed at the beginning. Lives most of his life in regret and laments the loss of his loved ones. He represents Cadmus, whose inability to let go of regret and accept loss brought him immense suffering. Eventually, like Cadmus he gets to possess the resurrection stone, and yet withers away in his own sorrow.

Clearly, the tale of the three brothers is a reflection of the character sketches of the pivotal characters of the series. So, to answer the question, I guess **Antioch** would have been in **Slytherin**, while **Cadmus** and **Ignotus** would have been in **Gryffindor**.

Comment: I'm not sure that Cadmus would have been in Gryffindor, although I like your reasoning.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I had not thought of that parallel.

Comment: I like ykombinator's parallel's between the Peverell brothers and Harry, Voldemort, and Dumbledore, but wouldn't it make more sense to parallel Cadmus with Snape? Talk about someone who was obsessed by his lost love! Consumed by his own sorrow at losing Lily to James, then losing her when Voldemort killed her, then struggling with her memory every time he saw Harry. "Look at me... you have your mother's eyes."

Comment: Sometimes while reading such brilliant answers as this one, I often wonder that J.K.Rowling might not have meant it to be this way herself but it turns out that it fits the fiction perfectly.

Comment: Cadmus was Snape. Dumbledore was death.

Answer (score 2):

Antioch would have been in Slytherin as he clearly has self interest at heart and had the desire for ultimate power. Add to that his willingness to kill someone over a quarrel. Cadmus would likely have been in Hufflepuff as he doesn't exude a desire for power, cleverness, or bravery. It's Hufflepuff that takes the rest. Ignotus was humble and clever. I don't see him as particularly brave. He could have been but the story says nothing of it. I believe he would have been in Ravenclaw.

Comment: I see Ignotus as extremely brave, to have been able to think up a solution to a problem like that that fast and keep his cool while answering, instead of peeing his pants in horror at the sight of Death himself. In fact, all of them were pretty brave in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that they were all brave, but I do not think they would have all ended up in Gryffindor. Antioch was selfish and wanted only to better himself, so I believe he would have been a Slytherin. Cadmus, on the other hand, was unable to betray the love he felt for his would be bride. This speaks of a Hufflepuff, but I feel he was also the one to lead them to that river in an attempt to confront Death, very much a Gryffindor trait. I believe that he could have gone into either house. Ignotus, the story tells us, was very wise. It does not call him smart, it calls him wise. Since all three were well learned in the magical arts, they would have all had to be smart. He also displays a great loyalty to his brothers when he faced Death with them, for he did not seek anything from Death. He would be unsuited for Ravenclaw as he did not want to make himself better than others, as he was called a humble man. He would have gone into Hufflepuff or Gryffindor for in his second meeting with Death, Ignotus met his gladly and went with him willingly.

Answer (score 0):

Being that they were super-gifted wizards, there's a chance they would all be in Ravenclaw.

Comment: Not a bad guess, although extraordinary magic has been created by members of other Houses as well -- the Marauders' Map, for example.

Comment: @JoeWhite - there was a speculation (well founded) here on SFF that Marauder's map was NOT a super extraordinary piece of magic. Clever, but not uber-exceptional.

Answer (score -2):

You guys are missing the whole point. All three were in Gryffindor. If one of the brothers were in Gryffindor, all must have stayed in the same house and all were very, very brave like Godric Griyffindor. It is obvious Ignotus was in Gryffindor, so rest were no different from him. Had Antioch or Cadmus been in another house, their qualities would have defined evil or dumb or clever. They were not clever, they were brave.

Comment: There is no canonical reason stating that brothers have to be in Gryffindor. There is nothing stating that they were all brave either.

Comment: Looks like you need to read this question and its answers: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7235/3267

Comment: Also, there's really no evidence any of them were brave.

Comment: In fact the Pavarti twins were in separate houses.