# What houses are the Patil twins in?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, sorting-hat

In the *Muggles Guide to Harry Potter* it says that one of the Patil twins is in Gryffindor and the other is in Ravenclaw.
But then in the Goblet of Fire movie, they are both in the Gryffindor common room.
So are they both in Gryffindor or what?

Comment: Standard answer to HP questions on SE... The films are wrong ;)

Comment: In any case, it is always possible to invite people from other houses into your house's common room.

Answer (score 40):

This appears to be a mistake/change in the films as referenced in this [wikia page on the twins](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Padma_and_Parvati_Patil).

> Padma Patil: While depicted as a Gryffindor in the movies, she is sorted as a Ravenclaw in the books.

This is backed up by a [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7237/58193) by @Kevin to a related question and the following quote.

> Brothers and sisters usually go in the same Houses, don’t they?” [Harry] said. He was judging by the Weasleys, all seven of whom had been put into Gryffindor.
>
> “Oh no, not necessarily,” said Hermione. “Parvati Patil’s twin’s in Ravenclaw, and they’re identical. You’d think they’d be together, wouldn’t you?”
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 12 (*The Triwizard Tournament*)

The Pottermore articles on the two also show the following.

- [Padma Patil](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/padma-patil): Ravenclaw
- [Parvati Patil](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/parvati-patil): Gryffindor

Comment: They never strike me as twins in the movies, I mean they look very different, whereas they are supposed to be identical in the book.

Comment: @DarthPaghius For the record they could still be nonidentical twins. I'm a twin and look nothing like my brother.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Except it says they are identical... :/

Comment: @DavidMulder In the books aye but I was just commenting that just because they don't look similar doesn't mean they can't be twins.

Comment: I know there is a strong sense on this site that the books are "right" and any divergence from them by the movies is "wrong". That said, it may have been a conscious decision on the part of the filmmakers to put both sisters in Gryffindor, and not a "mistake".

Comment: @GreenMatt Conscious decision or not the films are meant to be in the same canon as the books (as per my limited understanding) and so any deviation from them should be considered a mistake.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Not sure where you got that understanding, as I don't think many people have it. That said, my point is that "mistake" implies an oversight or other sort of unintentional error. I don't have a source to back it up, but honestly don't think that was the case here - I expect the filmmakers thought it would be easier to present the sisters as being from the same house, rather than split them up for something that is inconsequential to the plot.

Answer (score 13):

## Padma is Ravenclaw in the books but Gryffindor in the movies.

The reason that Padma is in the Gryffindor common room in the movies is because in the movies, she *is* a Gryffindor. Both Patil twins are Gryffindor in the movies - we can see that from their Gryffindor ties.

[image]

This isn’t just a one-time error either. They’re consistently both shown as being Gryffindors throughout the movies. They both are consistently wearing the red-collared Gryffindor robes with the house crest on them and the ties whenever they are seen in uniform.

[image]

In the books, however, Padma is a Ravenclaw and Parvati is a Gryffindor.

> “Well …’ said Parvati slowly, ‘I suppose my sister might … Padma, you know … in Ravenclaw. I’ll ask her if you like.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 22 (The Unexpected Task)*</sup></sub>

So, *The Muggles’ Guide to Harry Potter* is right for the books, but in the movies, Padma is consistently a Gryffindor.

Comment: Maybe because, in the movies, they don't look identical, so the screenwriters considered them a separate and unique set of twins, both of whom were chosen to be in Gryffindor